# Why is this cat making this sound?

Tags: cats, vocalizations

I want to know why the cat in this video: https://youtu.be/WdbB_6mlCPw?t=521
is making this sound.  Is a particular meow of that breed or...?

Answer (score 2):

It's not breed dependent. The cat is terrified in this video.

The ears pasted back on the head, wide eyes, swishing tail, hair fluffed up are all signs of fear based aggression.

The sound is how distressed the cat is. Trying to warn the mannequin head to go away. This sound is not breed specific, but behavioural specific. There's variation between the sounds cat's make, as there's variation in the colour of their fur.

Answer (score 2):

It's not about breed, my cat which isn't of any special breed made this kind of sound a few times and it was at the vet when taking injections. He was terrified and it was the last warning before carrying out an attack as nothing else was left to escape from the situation.

Comment: This is a threatening warning to back off before the cat attacks. Threat posturing like this is meant to prevent fights. It’s like saying “Back off! I don’t want to fight, but if you keep it up I will hurt you. -cat”